# Is mechanically slaughtered chicken halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, halal-certification

I live in USA and as we know maximum chicken of USA is mechanically slaughtered. So if a chicken is mechanically slaughtered in the name of Allah and the machine is supervised by a Muslim, is that chicken is Halal to eat? Can you please answer me with proper reference?

Thansk in advance

Answer (score 1):

i have a friend who told me he approached a mufti on 3 occasions in regards to this question. supposedly on the first 2 occasions the mufti told him to leave it with him and the 3rd occasion he said Janna is not cheap as in to imply that machine slaughtered is not permissible.